# Can we add a new arbiter in Gem5 simulator (Garnet 2.0)

Tags: network-programming, simulator, gem5, system-on-chip

i would like to develop a new router arbiter.
Can GEM5 (Garnet2.0) simulator accept  a new arbiter. i know that it implements Round Robin arbiter.

Thanks

Comment: Hum.. And so, what is the question ? What is your problem ? What did you do and what you not succeed to do ?

Comment: I just want to have the experiences of others on this point(arbiter). I have not decided to use GEM5 yet. the goal of my work is to develop a new arbiter that supports real-time applications.Is GEM5 i the right simulator to validate my contribution? Is GEM5(garnet2.0)  extensible(in term of arbiter)?